# How do I rename a photo album in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, photos

After creating a photo album in Facebook, I can't seem to figure out how to rename the album caption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the album then click "Edit Photos", then click "Edit Info". This will allow you to edit the album name, location, and description.

Answer (score 4):

Go to album and click on `Edit Photos`, you can find `Edit Info` in there.

In 'Edit Photos', click on "Untitled Album' and change it to whatever you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Just click on "Untitled album". It will get converted into a text box. Delete "Untitled Album" and write your chosen name for the album. Simple.